# is this a valid ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby

```
if step.include? "apples" or "banana" or "cheese"
say "yay"
end
```

Comment: You can check that yourself by getting an IDE that can work with Ruby.

Comment: Don't waste your time with an IDE when you don't need one.  `irb` is the proper way to check stuff like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several issues with your code.

```
step.include? "apples" or "banana" or "cheese"
```

This expression evaluates to:

```
step.include?("apples") or ("banana") or ("cheese")
```

Because Ruby treats all values other than `false` and `nil` as true, this expression will always be true.  (In this case, the value `"banana"` will [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) the expression and cause it to evaluate as true, even if the value of step does not contain any of these three.)

Your intent was:

```
step.include? "apples" or step.include? "banana" or step.include? "cheese"
```

However, this is inefficient.  Also it uses `or` instead of `||`, which has a different operator precedence, and usually shouldn't be used in `if` conditionals.

Normal `or` usage:

```
do_something or raise "Something went wrong."
```

A better way of writing this would have been:

```
step =~ /apples|banana|cheese/
```

This uses a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which you're going to use a lot in Ruby.

And finally, there is no `say` method in Ruby unless you define one.  Normally you would print something by calling `puts`.

So the final code looks like:

```
if step =~ /apples|banana|cheese/
  puts "yay"
end
```

Comment: do i add /i for case insensitive ? is this like regex  ? ty.

Comment: Yes, it would be `step =~ /apples|banana|cheese/i`

Answer (score 3):

The last two terms appear to Ruby as true, rather than having anything to do with the `include?` phrase.

Assuming that `step` is a string...

```
step = "some long string with cheese in the middle"
```

you could write something like this.

```
puts "yay" if step.match(/apples|banana|cheese/)
```

Comment: If it's in a conditional (like yours) you could also do: `puts "yay" if step =~ /apples|banana|cheese/`

Comment: (for those that don't know, because `puts "yay" if 0` will execute the puts, but `puts "yay" if nil` wont)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to call `step.include?` on each of the arguments until one of them returns `true`:

```
if ["apples", "banana", "cheese"].any? {|x| step.include? x}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not what you appear to be wanting. The `include?` method takes in a `String`, which is not what `"apples" or "banana" or "cheese"` produces. Try this instead:

`puts "yay" if ["apples", "banana", "cheese"].include?(step)`

But it's unclear from the context what step is supposed to be. If it's just the single word, then this is fine. If it can be a whole sentence, try joel.neely's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to that syntax that would do what you appear to want would be something like:

```
  if ["apples", "banana", "cheese"].include?(step)
    puts "yay"
  end
```

But one of the other suggestions using a regex would be more concise and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `step` is an `Array` or a `Set` or something else that supports set intersection with the `&` operator, I think the following code is the most idiomatic:

```
unless (step & ["apples","banana","cheese"]).empty?
  puts 'yay'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add some parentheses for you:

```
if (step.include? "apples") or ("banana") or ("cheese")
    say "yay"
end
```

(That would be why it's always saying "yay" -- because the expression will always be true.)

Answer (score -1):

Just to add another side to this...

If `step` *is* an `Array` (as calling `include?` seems to suggest) then maybe the code should be:

```
if (step - %w{apples banana cheese}) != step
  puts 'yay'
end
```

Comment: The most confusing and computation intensive variant.

Comment: I don't know about confusing. That's pretty silly. As far as 'computation intensive'... well, I wasn't exactly putting effort into an efficient algorithm, but it isn't that bad.